# Inheriting functions from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
const startGame = {
 time : 0,
 start : function(){

 }
 next : function(){
 
 }

 end : function(){

 }
}


const anotherGame = { //want to inherit from startGame
 startAnother : function(){} //want to inherit from startGame.start
}
```

Given an object like this, I would like to inherit from it and give it a new property. For example, `anotherGame` extends `startGame` and takes all other properties, but I want to write additional code in addition to the properties of `start` function of `startGame` except for `anotherStart` function. What should I do ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do here. Inheritance is something that happens to classes (and constructor functions) rather than on plain objects or regular functions. It would probably help if you provided a simple example of what you were trying to acheive instead of a collection of completely empty functions and a very vague description of how you want to build on it.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, ES6 classes use prototype to achieve inheritance:

```js
const startGame = {
  time: 0,
  start: function () {
    console.log("works", this.time);
  },
  next: function () {},
  end: function () {},
};

const anotherGame = {
  //want to inherit from startGame
  startAnother: function () {
    this.start();
  }, //want to inherit from startGame.start
};

// Magic happens here
Object.setPrototypeOf(anotherGame, startGame);

anotherGame.startAnother();
```

Using ES6 classes:

```js
class StartGame {
  time = 0;

  start() {
    console.log("works", this.time);
  }
  next() {}
  end() {}
}

class AnotherGame extends StartGame {
  startAnother() {
    this.start();
  }
}

const anotherGame = new AnotherGame();

anotherGame.startAnother();
```